# Is prolonged Phd in accounting means the end of your academic career?

Tags: academic-life

I have completed my PhD this month, but this month also marked the completion of 8 years of my PhD journey. Standing on the new road ( and long road) of establishing myself as an academic. I wander if it is really worth of putting the efforts. Will the fast or productive publication from now on be enough to save me in establishing in the academic world? I do have three publication under my belt which formed the basis for my thesis. Any comments would be truly appreciated. THANK YOU.

Comment: The body does not seem to be related to the title

Comment: In general it depends on the field. This would not be as much of a concern in history as it would in theoretical physics. I don't know about accounting, but it's been my impression that business schools have great difficulty in attracting Ph.D. faculty, unlike many other fields (especially history and theoretical physics). I suspect that someone who took 8 years to get a Ph.D. in accounting would have at least an order of magnitude (maybe even two orders of magnitude) less difficulty in getting an academic position than someone who took 4 years to get a Ph.D. in theoretical physics.

Comment: Important to consider that there is more than one path that can be taken. A simple example is if you spent 8 years not being all about fast publication, why start now? Things can change and it can be right for you, that's fine - but there are still paths open to people that doesn't involve churning out lots of publications. Only you can decide if it would be worth it, or even worth attempting. Some definitely think it is, perhaps most people overall (in most fields) decide it isn't, and outcomes are all over the place, in academia and beyond. It's ok to review your options before deciding.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. @ Azor Ahai- I wander if there even exist a room for me to develop a career in academia or should I simply switch to industry.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to give an answer with so many variables going into "suitability", but I think that the time it took is probably overbalanced by the productivity you show and the promise you have for the future. And you won't know about your future chances until you get into the market.

At worst, it might depend on why it took longer than you think it should have. But if you have "reasons" for that then it shouldn't be much of an issue.

If your professors are happy with you and give you good (great) letters, then it will be eased considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a postdoc position first, if it works you will have a couple of years to see how it feels and decide what's next. If it doesn't work, at least you gave it your best so you won't regret anything.

After 8 years of PhD it's worth trying the academic path for 1 or 2 more years if that's what you're interested in:

- it's an opportunity to improve your academic profile
- it gives you a better understanding of what working in academia really means and whether it's something you'd like
- it's a valuable experience to have in your CV when applying for industry positions anyway so you wouldn't be wasting your time
- it pays better than a PhD